# Impossible to access or update class member with Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, segmentation-fault

I've been getting segmentation fault error with below code.

Header file is below

```
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QDateTime>

class TransactionFilterProxy : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TransactionFilterProxy(QObject *parent = 0);


    static const QDateTime MIN_DATE;

    static const QDateTime MAX_DATE;

    void setDateRange(const QDateTime &from, const QDateTime &to);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent) const;

private:

    QDateTime dateFrom;
    QDateTime dateTo;
};
```

And CPP file is below

```
#include "transactionfilterproxy.h"
#include "transactiontablemodel.h"
#include <QDateTime>
#include <cstdlib>

const QDateTime TransactionFilterProxy::MIN_DATE = QDateTime::fromTime_t(0);

const QDateTime TransactionFilterProxy::MAX_DATE = QDateTime::fromTime_t(0xFFFFFFFF);

TransactionFilterProxy::TransactionFilterProxy(QObject *parent) :
    QSortFilterProxyModel(parent),
    dateFrom(MIN_DATE),
    dateTo(MAX_DATE)
{

}

bool TransactionFilterProxy::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{


    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);

    int type = index.data(TransactionTableModel::TypeRole).toInt();
    QDateTime datetime = index.data(TransactionTableModel::DateRole).toDateTime();

    if( datetime < dateFrom || datetime > dateTo)  //crashes here
        return false;

    return true;
}

void TransactionFilterProxy::setDateRange(const QDateTime &from, const QDateTime &to)
{
    this->dateFrom = from; //crashes here
    this->dateTo = to;
    invalidateFilter();
}
```

Application crashes when the QDateTime class members **dateFrom**  was accessed.
Tried to run debug mode with QTcreator, it shows SIGSEGV error.
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a `TransactionFilterProxy` object, and it only crashes when it tries to access that data member. Whats the calling code?

Comment: Something like `transactionProxyModel = new TransactionFilterProxy();` and then `transactionProxyModel->setDateRange(QDateTime(current), TransactionFilterProxy::MAX_DATE); `

Comment: Never tried with virtural, what is the benefit with that, Alex F?

Comment: Maybe something wrong with data. Have you check your `datetime` is valid?

Comment: Yes, `datetime` had no issues

Comment: you can always prevent the crash by doing if(this) { this->dateFrom = from... } invalidateFilter();

Comment: After adding the if(this), it still crashes. Btw, if I add a new member of class before `dateFrom` is declared, it works. but I don't know why.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI the `if (this)` trick doesn't work, because modern compilers take advantage of the fact that that calling a method on a NULL object is undefined behavior, and therefore they assume that `this` can never be NULL and therefore they optimize the code by implicitly removing the `if (this)` test from the compiler program :)

Comment: "_Btw, if I add a new member of class before dateFrom is declared, it works. but I don't know why._"  Sounds like UB.